# Find Content Block path stored in Salesforce Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, ssjs

I would like to create a cloudpage where in it will take an input from a user for Content Block By Id. The goal is to achieve the path where this content block is stored. On entering the integer value of the content block, it should give me the path where it is stored. I was able to achieve the same for data extension. But not sure what would the object name be for retrieving a content block

Answer (score 0):

For assets in Content Builder, you need to use MC REST API

Check this reference: [asset Advanced Query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/assetAdvancedQuery.html)

Note: Your Installed Package scope should have `Read` check in the Assets section

```
Host: https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
POST /asset/v1/content/assets/query
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

A sample payload for the API call

```
{
    "query":
    {
            "property":"id",
            "simpleOperator":"equal",
            "value": YOUR_ASSET_ID
    },
    "fields":
    [
        "id",
        "name",
        "assetType",
        "category",
        "customerKey"
    ]
}
```

A sample response

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "page": 1,
    "pageSize": 50,
    "links": {},
    "items": [
        {
            "id": YOUR_ASSET_ID,
            "customerKey": "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX",
            "name": "Asset Name",
            "category": {
                "id": Folder_ID,
                "name": "Folder Name",
                "parentId": ParentFolder_ID
            },
.............
}
```